# Distinguish ajax requests from full requests in JSF custom validator

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2, http-headers

My validator needs to know if it is a full request or an ajax request. In my current solution I check the http request header for the `X-Requested-With` element:

```
public void validate(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) throws ValidatorException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) context.getExternalContext().getRequest();
        if (req.getHeader("X-Requested-With") != null) {
           // do something
        } else {
           // do something else
        }
       ...
}
```

Is there a better approach to achieve this? Is my solution "safe" with respect to different browsers / javascript libs?

**UPDATE:**

Just found out that the *X-Requested-With* header is only present if the ajax request comes from the Primefaces component library (the `<p:ajax>`tag).

It is **not** present if I use plain JSF `<f:ajax>`. **So my approach won't work with** `<f:ajax>`.

Using `<f:ajax>` there is a different header:

```
Faces-Request:partial/ajax
```

The solution proposed by Osw works for `<f:ajax>` **and** `<p:ajax>`:

[`PartialViewContext#isAjaxRequest()`](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/javadocs/javax/faces/context/PartialViewContext.html#isAjaxRequest%28%29)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would not rely on http header. Never tried it by myself, but you could do the following:

```
PartialViewContext pvc = facesContext.getPartialViewContext();
if(pvc.isAjaxRequest()) {
// ...
} else {
// ...
}
```

Another option is using `isPartialRequest()` instead of `isAjaxRequest()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sounds good. Do you know what the method does? Maybe just checks for headers too.

Comment: @Matt, sorry, no idea what it does exactly, but options are checking headers or checking request parameter map.

Comment: Updated my question. It looks like my solution isn't safe.

Comment: This is correct. And if you happen to use [OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/), there is the [`Faces`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/utils/Faces)-class, which provides `isAjaxRequest()` as a shortcut and is also available in EL as `#{faces.ajaxRequest}`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd that it is a reliable way to check it. This is exactly how for example Django checks for AJAX requests:

```
 def is_ajax(self):
        return self.META.get('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH') == 'XMLHttpRequest'
```

Also listed here as such:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Updated my questions. Seems like my solution isn't safe.