# Execute PrimeFaces p:poll concurrently

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Here is the first part of code : (goal = update a component every 2 seconds)

```
<p:poll id="pollid"
        async="true"
        immediate="true"
        interval="2"
        update="log"
        widgetVar="poll"/>
```

Here is the second part : (description = long-running function which will modify constantly the component "log")

```
<p:commandButton id="running"
                 value="#{Nbt.execution}"
                 actionListener="#{Nbt.launchModule}"
                 async="true"
                 ajax="true"
                 immediate="true"
                 update="log">
</p:commandButton>
```

Detail : "log" is the id of a `<p:inputTextarea>`

In theory, maybe it should work but my `<p:inputTextarea>` doesn't fill progressively.

It waits for the end of the "long-running" method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is when you `update` a `<p:inputTextarea>`, you're also *submitting* the current content of that text area, which is blank (the JSF lifecycle is applied to that component). Change your `<p:inputTextarea>` to an `<h:outputText>` and it should work.

To illustrate the problem, take this Facelets page:

```
<h:form>
    <p:inputTextarea id="txt_count" value="#{backingBean.text}"/>
    <p:poll interval="3" update="txt_count" />
    <p:commandButton value="Long running" async="true" action="#{backingBean.longRunning}"/>
</h:form>
```

And this backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class BackingBean {
    private String text = "";
    public String getText() {
        System.out.println("GET: " + text);
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        System.out.println("SET: " + text);
        this.text = text;
    }
    public void longRunning() throws InterruptedException {
        text = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            text += "a";
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Run it and click the button. The server log will show something like:

```
Info: GET: 
Info: GET: 
Info: SET: 
Info: GET: a
Info: SET: 
Info: GET: 
Info: GET: aaa
Info: SET: 
Info: GET: 
Info: GET: aaa
Info: SET: 
Info: GET: 
Info: GET: aaa
Info: SET: 
Info: GET:
```

You can also see this in the POST headers if you use your browser's developer tools.

Replace the `<p:inputTextarea>` with an `<h:outputText>` and it prints a growing string of characters.

Comment: I don't know how to thank you. It was simple and difficult. DavidS your answer was true. But if you give me this favour, I will profit to ask you a derived question : **If I want to use a `<p:inputTextarea />` what manipulation can I do to update my text constantly ?** I know you can answer me. Please.

Comment: @Aucxence, above code already do it, look at the this part of `<p:poll.../>`, ` update="txt_count"` it updates element `txt_count` whenever it invokes.

Comment: Actually Aucxence the `update` is part of the problem in this case: it's overwriting the contents of the **input** field with an empty string. @Aucxence, it depends on your situation. One way to "get it working" would be to make `setText` empty (but then it's not really an input field). Another would be to make `setText` conditional on not being an [AJAX update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428058/distinguish-ajax-requests-from-full-requests-in-jsf-custom-validator). It could be that neither of these options will suit your situation. I suggest you open another question if needed.